# Why can't I deserialize the response to my entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Environment**: VS 2017 Entity Framework 6.0

**Article Reference**
https://dzone.com/articles/a-few-great-ways-to-consume-restful-apis-in-c

**Question**:
How do I convert Web Api 2 call to my entity?

**Person Entity**

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

...

**Web API 2 Controller**

```
namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class PeopleController : ApiController
    {
        private testdbEntities db = new testdbEntities();

        // GET: api/People
        public IQueryable<Person> GetPeople()
        {
            return db.People;
        }
```

...

**Can't get last line to work**

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");
var response = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:49777/api/People");
var releases = JArray.Parse(response);  //This works
Person p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(response); //How do I get this to work?
```

...

**Error**:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException   HResult=0x80131500
>   Message=Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into
>   type 'WebApplication1.Person' because the type requires a JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error
>   either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or
>   change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a
>   collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can
>   be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be
>   added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path
>   '', line 1, position 1.   Source=Newtonsoft.Json   StackTrace:    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureArrayContract(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract)

[image]

Comment: why are you parsing as JsonArray in the first place?

Comment: It's from the article reference under WebClient class, just an example of what does work.

Comment: Your API endpoint `http://localhost:49777/api/People` must be returning array of `people` types, but you are trying to cast it to single `people` object.

Comment: Good catch! that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead..

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");
var response = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:49777/api/People");
var releases = JArray.Parse(response);  //This works
var people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person[]>(response);
```

Changed from this

```
Person p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(response);
```

to this..

```
var people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person[]>(response);
```

In the article link that you included in question, they are using an endpoint that returns a list of releases. That is the reason they are parsing it to Json Array first.

Depending on what you are returning from your endpoint, your code will change. But since you said `JArray.Parse(` line is executing successfully, I assume your endpoint is also returning list of people. So you need to deserialize it to list of `people` rather than single `people` object.

Comment: why does the article use JArray.Parse? The image above that shows content of releases object doesn't make sense to me.